Android – okhttp NullPointerException on Cookie.name()
Lately I started getting an exception in production, where the app complains about a NullPointerException when trying to access an okhttp's Cookie instance. We can't reproduce it, and it's quite confusing as not only the code is in Kotlin, using non nullable types, but cookies are mainly managed by okhttp.
Here's the start of the stacktrace:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String okhttp3.Cookie.name()' on a null object reference
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.cookieHeader(SourceFile:39)

Checking that cookieHeader method, we can see that it does try to access the name property of the cookie, as mentioned in the stacktrace (okhttp code):
private fun cookieHeader(cookies: List<Cookie>): String = buildString {
    cookies.forEachIndexed { index, cookie ->
      if (index > 0) append("; ")
      append(cookie.name).append('=').append(cookie.value) // here
    }
  }

This method is called in one place only, in the intercept method of the BridgeInterceptor (default okhttp interceptor):
// ...

    val cookies = cookieJar.loadForRequest(userRequest.url)
    if (cookies.isNotEmpty()) {
      requestBuilder.header("Cookie", cookieHeader(cookies)) // only called here
    }
// ...

Cookies come from that cookieJar instance, through the loadForRequest call. I'm the one injecting the cookieJar instance into okhttp. It follows the following interface (from okhttp):
interface CookieJar {
  /**
   * Saves [cookies] from an HTTP response to this store according to this jar's policy.
   *
   * Note that this method may be called a second time for a single HTTP response if the response
   * includes a trailer. For this obscure HTTP feature, [cookies] contains only the trailer's
   * cookies.
   */
  fun saveFromResponse(url: HttpUrl, cookies: List<Cookie>)

  /**
   * Load cookies from the jar for an HTTP request to [url]. This method returns a possibly
   * empty list of cookies for the network request.
   *
   * Simple implementations will return the accepted cookies that have not yet expired and that
   * [match][Cookie.matches] [url].
   */
  fun loadForRequest(url: HttpUrl): List<Cookie>

My implementation starts with 0 cookies, eventually saving some when okhttp calls that saveFromResponse method. Subsequent requests will then use whatever cookies that call stored through that loadForRequest call we saw earlier. Here's my implementation:
class OkHttpCookieJar() : CookieJar {

    companion object {
        var cookieStore = mutableMapOf<String, Cookie>()

        fun clearCookies() {
            cookieStore = mutableMapOf()
        }
    }

    override fun saveFromResponse(url: HttpUrl, cookies: List<Cookie>) {
        if (cookies.isEmpty()) {
            return
        }

        for (cookie in cookies) {
            cookieStore[cookie.name] = cookie
        }
    }

    override fun loadForRequest(url: HttpUrl): List<Cookie> {
        return cookieStore.values.toList()
    }
}

For completion's sake, here's where saveFromResponse is being called (oktthp code):
fun CookieJar.receiveHeaders(url: HttpUrl, headers: Headers) {
  if (this === CookieJar.NO_COOKIES) return

  val cookies = Cookie.parseAll(url, headers)
  if (cookies.isEmpty()) return

  saveFromResponse(url, cookies) // here
}

That Cookie.parseAll call internally calls a parse method that can return a null Cookie, but parseAll just skips it if it's null (okhttp code):
@JvmStatic
    fun parseAll(url: HttpUrl, headers: Headers): List<Cookie> {
      val cookieStrings = headers.values("Set-Cookie")
      var cookies: MutableList<Cookie>? = null

      for (i in 0 until cookieStrings.size) {
        val cookie = parse(url, cookieStrings[i]) ?: continue // skips to next iteration if null
        if (cookies == null) cookies = mutableListOf()
        cookies.add(cookie)
      }

      return if (cookies != null) {
        Collections.unmodifiableList(cookies)
      } else {
        emptyList()
      }
    }

Finally, my question: Given that I only save and return the cookies okhttp gives me, and I have non nullable types everywhere, where could that NullPointerException come from? I also access the cookie instance in saveFromResponse to use it's name as the key for the map without issues.
My first theory was that some Java code in okhttp was somehow managing to sneak in a null cookie, but the code in the version I'm using (4.10.0), is all in Kotlin.
Thanks in advance for any insight provided.
